Time series decomposition
I have a time series that I want to decompose.
Dataset (train - dataframe) example (stock price):
        Date    Close
7389    2014-12-24  104.589996
7390    2014-12-26  105.059998
7391    2014-12-29  105.330002
7392    2014-12-30  105.360001
7393    2014-12-31  104.5700

Here is my code:
train_dec = copy.deepcopy(train)
train_dec.index = pd.to_datetime(train_dec['Date'])
train_dec.index.freq = 'D'

# Transform DataFrame into a Series
train_series = train_dec['Close']

train_decomposition = seasonal_decompose(train_series, model='additive')

train_trend = train_decomposition.trend
train_seasonal = train_decomposition.seasonal
train_residual = train_decomposition.resid

I tried without converting into Series and with it. Tried set up frequency to 'D'.
I keep getting errors such as:

ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency D

or

ValueError: You must specify a period or x must be a pandas object with a PeriodIndex or a DatetimeIndex with a freq not set to None

when I do not set frequency.
Maybe it is because the data have gaps (weekends) when there is no data point (stock price). Should I convert it to a weekly format? But how can I do this if there are gaps (e.g. if I have removed outliers)?
It must be something trivial but I can not see the solution.
Your help is greatly appreciated!

You need to specify the period when doing seasonal decomposition:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import copy

data = {
    'Date': ['2014-12-24', '2014-12-26', '2014-12-29', '2014-12-30', '2014-12-31'],
    'Close': [104.589996, 105.059998, 105.330002, 105.360001, 104.5700]
}
train = pd.DataFrame(data)

train['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(train['Date'])
train.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

idx = pd.date_range(start=train.index.min(), end=train.index.max(), freq='D')
train = train.reindex(idx)

train['Close'] = train['Close'].ffill()

decomposition = seasonal_decompose(train['Close'], model='additive', period=3)  
fig = decomposition.plot()
plt.show()




so 'period' parameter is 1 (annual), 4 (quarterly),.. I guess that 12 for monthly, 52 weekly, and 365 for daily. Correct? Then what to do with the daily data with gaps? Use the value 52 for weekly?

Yes, then you need to use 52 for  weekly.
